# Trouble exiting 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm tyring to create a frequency counter. Basically, there's an array (`testArray`) with a bunch of numbers. I need to process those numbers and insert them in another array (`probabilityArray`). `probabilityArray` is also `2D` array with the 1st row being the unique elements from the test array, the 2nd row being how many times a unique number occurs (Ex. `probabilityArray[2][5]` represents how often the number at `probabilityArray[1][5]` occurs). I'm having trouble exiting the rows for loop and I have no idea why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int histogram() {

}

int entropy() {

}

int main() {
    int i, j, k, found = 0, currentPosition = 0, l = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    int testArray[10][10] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
                 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
                 {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 ,19, 20}, 
                 {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
                 {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
                 {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}, 
                 {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30},
                 {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}, 
                 {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}, 
                 {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}};

    int row = sizeof(testArray) / sizeof(testArray[0]);
    int col = sizeof(testArray[0]) / sizeof(testArray[0][0]);
    int elements = (row * col);

    printf("Elements: %d\n", elements);
    //printf("Rows: %d\nCols: %d\n", row, col);

    int probabilityArray[3][elements];

    for(x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for(y = 0; y < elements; y++) {
            //printf("X: %d\tY: %d\t", x, y);
                    probabilityArray[x][y] = 0;
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }

    //printf("Got here\n");

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", l);
            l++;
            int temp = testArray[i][j];
            for (k = 0; k < currentPosition; k++) {
                if (probabilityArray[1][k] == temp) {
                    //Element is not unique, increase occurance counter
                    printf("NOT UNIQUE: %d\n", temp);
                    probabilityArray[2][k]++;
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found == 0) {
                //Element is unique, add it to array
                printf("FOUND: %d\n", temp);
                probabilityArray[1][currentPosition] = temp;
                probabilityArray[2][currentPosition]++;     
                currentPosition++;      
                printf("Current Position: %d\n", currentPosition);  
            }
            found = 0;
        }
        printf("I: %d\tC: %d\n", i, j);
    } 
    for (i = 0; i < currentPosition; i++) {
        probabilityArray[3][i] = (int)((probabilityArray[2][i] / elements) * 100);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < currentPosition; i++) {
        printf("ELEMENT: %d\t\tFREQUENCY: %d\t\tPROBABILITY:%d\n", probabilityArray[1][i], probabilityArray[2][i], probabilityArray[3][i]);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How am I going out of bounds? I declared it as probabilityArray[3][elements] and loop using those variables.

Comment: Sorry, misread the code.

Comment: But you assign to `probabilityArray[3][i]` later, and the index 3 is out of bounds. (Your `probabilityArray` seems to store different things in the rows 0, 1 and 2. You could consider using a struct with expressive field names here.)

Comment: Your probability in percent will always be zero, because the division is an integer division. A better, although still rough, representation can be obtained by first multiplying with 100, then dividing. Maybe you should use a `double` here and use floating-point arithmetic. (Which nicely supports my idea of a struct.)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @MOehm i in probabilityArray[3][i] only goes up to currentPosition which at the very worst would be equal to elements, but not worse. And yeah a struct would be much better in this situation haha. Probability doesn't work right now either but that's not too important right now.

Comment: @JensGustedt I can't exit out of the rows loop. Not sure why.

Comment: You are interested in the scope of a `break` statement? So why don't you then put that in the question title? And why do you present us all that code? In C the `break` always jumps out of the innermost loop or `switch`. Was it this fact that made you stumble?

Comment: @user2929779: It's the other dimension where you have an out-of-bounds error. You assign to `probabilityArray[1, 2 or 3]`, wheras the valid indices are `0, 1 or 2`.

Comment: @MOehm Yeah that was it. Dammit. Such a stupid error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using indices `1`, `2`, and `3`, where you probably meant to use `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Here:

```
            if (probabilityArray[1][k] == temp) {  // Should it be 0??
                //Element is not unique, increase occurance counter
                printf("NOT UNIQUE: %d\n", temp);
                probabilityArray[2][k]++;          // Should it be 1??
```

and here:

```
            probabilityArray[1][currentPosition] = temp; // Should it be 0??
            probabilityArray[2][currentPosition]++;      // Should it be 1??
```

and here:

```
    probabilityArray[3][i] = (int)((probabilityArray[2][i] / elements) * 100);
    // Should it be  2      and                      1 ??
```

and here:

```
    printf("ELEMENT: %d\t\tFREQUENCY: %d\t\tPROBABILITY:%d\n",
           probabilityArray[1][i], probabilityArray[2][i], probabilityArray[3][i]);
    // Should be be 0, 1, and 2
```

Fixing those might fix your problems.